# Count numbers of elements in rows considering start column connected to index variable in the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Hi everybody I am triying to solve a little problem in R. I have the next data frame (I add `dput()` version in the final part):

```
   ID Index   s1   s2   s3   s4   s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s10
1  a     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A
2  b     3 <NA> <NA>    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A
3  c     5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    A  A  A  A  A   A
4  d     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A
5  e     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A
6  f     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A
7  g     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A
8  h     4 <NA> <NA> <NA>    A    A  A  A  A  A   A
```

In my data frame `Test`, `Index` show the first non ocurrence of `NA` in each row. Now I would like to compute for each row in a new variable, the number of `A` considering columns like this: first column would be the column where is the first non `NA` occurence, for example in the case of `b` `ID` it has `Index=3` and I want to count the number of `A` since this column until 4 columns later, in this case until column `s3+4=s7`. This for all rows. I would like to get something like this:

```
   ID Index   s1   s2   s3   s4   s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s10 Count
1  a     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A   5
2  b     3 <NA> <NA>    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A   5
3  c     5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    A  A  A  A  A   A   5  
4  d     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A   5
5  e     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A   5
6  f     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A   5
7  g     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A   5
8  h     4 <NA> <NA> <NA>    A    A  A  A  A  A   A   5
```

I used this code but I got a mistake:

```
Test$Count=apply(Test[,c(-1,-2,Test$Index.Test$Index+4)] , 1 , function(x) length(which(!is.na(x) & x=="A")))
```

Please your help is welcome, the `dput()` version of my data frame is the next:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), 
    Index = c(1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6, 6, 4), s1 = c("A", NA, NA, "A", 
    "A", NA, NA, NA), s2 = c("A", NA, NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA
    ), s3 = c("A", "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, NA), s4 = c("A", 
    "A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, "A"), s5 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", NA, NA, "A"), s6 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A"), s7 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), s8 = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), s9 = c("A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), s10 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A")), .Names = c("ID", "Index", "s1", "s2", "s3", 
"s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "s10"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks a lot of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easier approach:

```
mcol <- ncol(Test) - 2
Test$Count <- sapply(seq(nrow(Test)), function(x) {
  idx <- Test$Index[x]
  idx2 <- seq(idx, min(idx + 4, mcol))
  sum(Test[x, -(1:2)][, idx2] == "A", na.rm = TRUE)
})


  ID Index   s1   s2   s3   s4   s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s10 Count
1  a     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
2  b     3 <NA> <NA>    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
3  c     5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
4  d     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
5  e     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
6  f     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A     5
7  g     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A     5
8  h     4 <NA> <NA> <NA>    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
```

Comment: Thanks @SvenHohenstein but I can't identify the count of A and I can have other letters like B,C,etc. And I wish to count it.

Comment: Dear @SvenHohenstein I am using other similar data frame and I got this error:`Error en `[.data.frame`(Test[x, -(1:2)], , idx2) : 
  undefined columns selected`. Could you help me please I add my data frame in the next link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83787253/Test.RData I don't know how to solve this problem please.

Comment: @Duck See the update. This code works with your actual data frame too.

Answer (score 0):

This variation will count As.  Don't know if you actually have other possible letters, but if you do, you'll need to do something like this:

```
cbind(
  Test,
  Count=apply(
    Test[-1], 1, 
    function(x) sum(x[-1][x[[1]]:(as.numeric(x[[1]]) + 4)] == "A")
) )

#   ID Index   s1   s2   s3   s4   s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 s10 Count
# 1  a     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 2  b     3 <NA> <NA>    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 3  c     5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 4  d     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 5  e     1    A    A    A    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 6  f     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 7  g     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  A  A  A  A   A     5
# 8  h     4 <NA> <NA> <NA>    A    A  A  A  A  A   A     5
```

I think the main issue with your approach is you're trying to mix positive and negative indices for the columns of `Test`.  It's also not entirely clear what `Test$Index.Test$Index` is inside your `apply`.